# Choosing projection in Eastern Australia (NSW in particular) for buffer in metres

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, buffer, australia

I am using QGIS.

Which projections / CRS are best to use for Eastern Australia (NSW in particular), which I can use to buffer points and lines in metres rather than degrees?

Answer (score 5):

For state-wide GIS data in NSW the [Map projections](https://www.spatial.nsw.gov.au/surveying/geodesy/projections) page of NSW Spatial Services says:

> **GDA Lambert Projection for NSW (GDA94 Lambert, GDA2020 Lambert)**
>
> This Lambert projection is suitable for state-wide GIS data in NSW. To
> ensure uniformity across agencies, the Surveyor General has endorsed
> the following parameters for use with GDA94 and GDA2020 data.

```
Projection: Conformal Conic
Standard Parallels: -30º 45' 00"
-35º 45' 00"
Latitude of Origin: -33º 15' 00"
Central Meridian:   147º 00' 00"
False Easting:  9 300 000
False Northing: 4 500 000
Units:  Metre
Ellipsoid:  GRS80
```

Comment: Good choice for NSW and only little over into adjacent states based on the limited information given in the question EPSG:3308 NSW Lamberts using GDA94 datum and EPSG:8058 NSW Lamberts using GDA2020 datum... If you're going further outside the state there are EPSG:3577 GDA94 / Australian Albers and EPSG:9473 GDA2020 / Australian Albers (not fully implemented in some software yet) though the distortion is probably as bad as Google Mercator.